# AIX OS fileset with status Broken

Tags: upgrade, aix

Does someone encounter this error in AIX version 7.1 TL3?

```
root@TEST:/ # lppchk -v
```

the result is:

```
lppchk: A parsing error occured for bos.sysmgt.quota 7.1.3.0
      on line 1, column 23.
      Instead of (, one of the following was expected:
               a '>' (to start a group) or 
               *prereq, *instreq, *coreq, *ifreq or
      a fileset name.
      Use local problem reporting procedures.
```

And something looks like this:

```
root@TEST:/ # oslevel -rl 7100-03
Fileset                                  Actual Level            Recommended ML
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  bos.pmapi.tools                        7.1.12.15               7.1.3.0
```

And this...

```
root@TEST:/ # lslpp -l | grep pmapi
   bos.pmapi.events        7.1.0.3     APPLIED       .0.0) 3.1.5.1
   bos.pmapi.lib           7.1.0.3     COMMITED      Performance Monitor API
   bos.pmapi.pmsvcs        7.1.0.3     COMMITED      Performance Monitor API Kernel
   bos.pmapi.samples       7.1.0.3     COMMITED      Performance Monitor API
   bos.pmapi.tools         7.1.0.3     BROKEN        Performance Monitor API Tools
   bos.pmapi.pmsvcs        7.1.0.3     COMMITED      Performance Monitor API Kernel
   bos.pmapi.tools         7.1.0.3     BROKEN        Performance Monitor API Tools
```

Comment: Looks like a potential ODM corruption to me.  Not sure how to work around it, but depending on the dependencies on bos.sysmgt.quota you could try just removing it and re-adding it.  The BROKEN filesets may be the result of the same ODM corruption, it's not possible to say without more diagnostics which you can't get due to the parse error.